# Android native code raises a SIGILL fault on the emulator when using -march=armv6 option

Tags: android, native-code, fault

I am trying Android NDK sample bitmap-plasma. I have added to the Android.mk the line

> LOCAL_CFLAGS := -march=armv6

but i get a SIGILL fault when running it on the emulator. Otherwise, it works.
I am working with the latest NDK (using cygwin) and the updated SDK.
Why this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that currently Android emulator only support (officially) armv5 native code.